# Php include txt with second txt as a backup

Tags: php

I didn't found a solution for my project on stack.

I'm using a php include txt file and i need a backup solution in my code.

For example:
My code is using Description.txt and if a client deletes this file i need to use the second file Description2.txt as a backup.

Something like this:

```
<php

? include Description.txt ! Description2.txt

# If file Description.txt no long exist, use Description2.txt as a backup.

?>
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: https://php.net/include - look for the return value.

Comment: Please note that giving client an interface to manipulate the content of "Description.txt" like upload or textarea without sanitization is potentially serious vulnerability, because anything inside that file is handled and processed as php ! You should consider another way to read content of that file, without interpreting its content as php like file_get_contents.

Comment: Surely better to store user-generated content in a database and load it from there. The current approach is brittle and risky, and it's unclear why it was chosen specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to `include` a file that doesn't exists will emit an E_WARNING. You can avoid that by using `file_exists()`

```
If (file_exists('description.txt'))
    include 'description.txt'
else
    include 'otherdescription.txt'
```

Comment: What if the file gets deleted between the file_exists() check and including it?

Comment: @hakre If that sort of race condition is a serious possibility then careful engineering will be required. I'd argue that including a user-accessible file is not a good idea, and some other solution should be found

Comment: Thank you for your full answer! I t tried your code, but is not working for me ... txt files can't be readed.  <pre><?= htmlspecialchars(
        @file_get_contents('products/adidas/colors/size/description.txt')
            ?: file_get_contents('products/adidas/description.txt')
) ?></pre>

Comment: Thank you tangentially for your answer. I tried your code, but is not working. <?php if (file_exists('products/adidas/admin/uploads/description.txt'))
    include 'products/adidas/admin/uploads/description.txt'
else
    include 'products/adidas/description.txt'
?>

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add ; after first include! your code works perfectly if  you use html + ckeditor.  Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

```php
1 === (@include 'Description.txt') || (include 'Description2.txt');
```

From the PHP manual (https://php.net/include):

> Handling Returns: `include` returns `FALSE` on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return `1`.

Some details as the expression may appear shy:

- The include is not a function, but a language construct. As the example above forms a complex expression, it is within parenthesis.
- Using || this way is a left-hand shorthand, PHP won't execute the right-hand side if the left-hand side is true

Written as an if clause:

```php
if (1 !== (@include 'Description.txt')) {
    include 'Description2.txt';
}
```

- If your customer not only deletes but also puts PHP code inside the file, anything is possible.
- The @ error suppression operator will likely hide such circumstances, I only treat this kind of code as it is.

---

Likely better for a .txt case (the same semantics otherwise apply):

```php
<pre><?= htmlspecialchars(
        @file_get_contents('Description.txt')
            ?: file_get_contents('Description2.txt')
) ?></pre>
```

See https://php.net/file_get_contents (and the return value again) as well as for [?: the ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (*"It is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator"*) that is able to do shorthand *and* return the value (here file contents).

Comment: Thank you for your full answer. I tried your code, but is not reading the txt files.

Comment: Yes, this typically requires debugging as well. Double check all pathnames are correct, the include path directive is setup to your liking and you checked error logging is enabled and you're keeping track of it. Remove the error suppression operator while you're debugging this as it prevents error messages, that it is for. Btw. I tested this code with PHP 8.2 on the development webserver and it worked.

Comment: It's working! Thank you very much. I removed the pre and now that bar is gone.

Comment: if <pre> was an issue, perhaps you also may want to remove the wrapping htmlspecialchars( ... ) as well. I was under the impression you wan to use it in HTML context. An alternative (after removal) might be readfile() https://php.net/readfile instead of file_get_contents() then.

Answer (score 0):

```
// If you have multiple backup files to be evaluated,
// you can use the following code

function checkValidFile(array $collection): void
{
    foreach ($collection as $file) {
        if (true === is_file($file)) {
            include $file;
            break;
        }
    }
}

$collection = [
    'description.txt',
    'description2.txt',
    'description3.txt',
];

checkValidFile($collection);
```

Comment: I tried your code, but i got blank page on php 7.4 :(

Comment: Try changing the function declaration to the following:
function checkValidFile($collection)

(remove array and :void)